# Asp.net auto focus of required field validator is not working in safari

Tags: asp.net, validation, safari

I am working with asp.net web forms application. In a page there are required field validators. If I miss any required field and click in the submit button required field validator should show error and automatically focus on the missed input field. It is working in the all major browser like chrome, firefox,IE. But auto focusing is not working in safari 9.0.1.

Am I missing anything or any change required ? Thanks in advance.

Here is my sample code:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFirstName" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="First Name" />
<span class="help-block text-left">
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="txtFirstName" ValidationGroup="send" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" CssClass="left" Font-Size="14px" ForeColor="#da7070" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></span>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `SetFocusOnError` to `true`. Default behaviour is false.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtFirstName" ValidationGroup="send" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" CssClass="left" Font-Size="14px" ForeColor="#da7070" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```