# ASP.NET: After POST validation fails focus is on the first input. How to remove that?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

After the validation fails ( if input is empty) for POST form, the cursor is set on the first input that has failed and the validation styling disappears:

[image]

I tried using jquery functions like `.blur()` or `.focusout()` after Login button is clicked, but it did not work.

Any suggestions how to remove the cursor from any text fields after POST validation fails?

Comment: Your question states asp.net, but your tags are for MVC - if it's asp.net, then use `SetFocusOnError="false"` from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41428936/asp-net-auto-focus-of-required-field-validator-is-not-working-in-safari

Comment: Just a thought, but have you tried adding a callback that is used when the function from the controller returns an error? Some snippets of code might help (something like the form and what it's using to make the POST, and what you've tried using for addressing the problem).

Comment: If you're POSTing the form, then bluring the button would have no effect as that instance will no longer exist as the page is re-rendered with new HTML.

Comment: Alternatively: `$(function() { if (document.activeElement != document.body) document.activeElement.blur(); });` from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21551843/2181514

Comment: There's probably a way to configure the validator not to do this though (ie do it properly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

would this work?

```
 $('form').submit(function () {
                if (!$('form').valid()) {
                    $('input').blur();
                }         
            });
```